# Trocar posição de dois caracteres em javascript

Tags: javascript

Ao usar a linguagem `C`, podemos trocar facilmente dois caracteres de uma string lugar, basta fazer:

```
aux = str[i];
str[i] = str[j];
str[j] = aux;
```

> Por exemplo: "ABCD" ficaria "ABDC"

porem, estou tendo muita dificuldade em fazer isso usando javascript. Alguém conhece um método que faça exatamente isso?

Comment: Não era exatamente isso que eu queria. Editei a pergunta pra ficar mais claro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No Javascript é possível fazer da mesma maneira, porém é necessário quebrar a `string` para `array` anteriormente usando as funções de [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) e depois unir com [join](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp). Porque a string é imutável (os valores imutáveis ​​(incapazes de alterar ou mutar) são valores primitivos - números, strings, booleanos, nulos, indefinidos). Enquanto os mutáveis são todos os outros objetos. Eles são geralmente referidos como tipos de referência porque os valores do objeto são referências à localização, na memória, de que o valor reside.)

```
var str = 'ABCD'.split('');
var i = 1;
var j = 2;

var aux = str[i];    
str[i] = str[j];
str[j] = aux;    
str = str.join('');
console.log(str);
```

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/xvwfnmd2/

Comment: É necessário... porque o tipo *string* é imutável no JavaScript, enquanto o tipo *array* é mutável. Essa informação é necessária na resposta :D

Comment: Vou ajustar. obrigado

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
var a = "abcd"
a.replace(a[3], a[2]).replace(a[2], a[3])
```

Comment: eu testei e deu certo, isso porque, como disseram acima, strings são imutáveis, logo, para o código acima funcionar temos que colocar ele dentro de uma variável, e imprimir essa nova variável.

Comment: Aliás, essa não é uma solução ao problema. O que você está fazendo é substituir os caracteres 'c' por 'd' e 'd' por 'c', porém se a string possuir estes caracteres repetidos, não irá funcionar. Para verificar, basta fazer `a = "cdcd"`, ao invés de permutar os caracteres 2 e 3, irá permutar 0 e 1, pois são as primeiras letras 'c' e 'd' que o JS encontra na *string*.